# how to add new array to an global session array in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5, laravel-session

I want to add new arrays to an global session array in laravel 5.6

The global session is `cart`.
I want add items to this array.

I try this:

for first time:

```
$item = ['key' => 'val1'];

session()->push('cart', $item);
dd(session()->get('cart'));
```

It works:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "key" => "val1"
  ]
]
```

Now, I change `$item = ['key' => 'val1'];` to `$item = ['key' => 'val2'];` and refresh the page again.

but it remove `"key" => "val1"` and return this:

```
array:1 [▼
      0 => array:1 [▼
        "key" => "val2"
      ]
    ]
```

what's my wrong?

Comment: How does it this change is performed? Can you please paste that operation code? Moreover, if you change val1 to val2 it is supposed to right to happen.

Answer (score 0):

So, everything is correct here. First you add `val1` under `key`. It is stored on SESSION. Next you **replace** `val1` with `val2`. You can either add `val2` under `key2`, or use dot notation:

```
session()->push('cart.key', `val1`);
session()->push('cart.key', `val2`);
dd(session()->get('cart'));
```

Answer (score 0):

for more details https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-session

```
session()->get('key');

session()->put('key', $value);

session(['chairs' => 7, 'instruments' => 3]);
```